# how to query for last n month's max amount and corersponding date

Tags: sql-server-2008

given a date like '2017-12-10'
I know how to query for previous month's min amount with the corresponding date:

```
Begin
  declare a_dt date
  declare dt1 date
  declare dt2 date

  select 
select  amt, valuation_dt, 
 'min in the mth' 'note'  from dba.summary_by_fin_grp
 where fi_group_cd='RBCFG'
and valuation_dt between '2017-11-01' and '2017-11-30 23:59:59.999'
and net_ValueWOBankAcct = 
(select  min(net_ValueWOBankAcct) from dba.summary_by_fin_grp
  where fi_group_cd='RBCFG'
 and valuation_dt between '2017-11-01' and '2017-11-30 23:59:59.999')
```

I know also I can loop with

```
while expr 
begin
    ...
end
```

Now how do go about returning min value with the date for **each month** in n last previous months without hard-coding with aid of c#

please note I will eventually like to list also the max value

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this:

```
AND valuation_dt BETWEEN '2017-11-01' AND '2017-11-30 23:59:59.999'
```

This is easier and accurate no mater how much time precsiion applies in the data:

```
AND valuation_dt >='2017-11-01' AND valuation_dt < '2017-12-01'
```

Note how that is actually shorter as well :)

For the minimum, use the "analytic" form of that function `MIN() OVER`

```
SELECT
      amt
    , valuation_dt
    , min_in_month
    , 'note'
FROM (
      SELECT
            amt
          , valuation_dt
          , net_ValueWOBankAcct
          , MIN(net_ValueWOBankAcct) OVER (PARTITION BY fi_group_cd) AS min_in_month
          , 'note'
      FROM dba.summary_by_fin_grp
      WHERE fi_group_cd = 'RBCFG'
      AND valuation_dt >= '2017-11-01' AND valuation_dt < '2017-12-01'
      ) d
WHERE net_ValueWOBankAcct = min_in_month
```

You can also use something like the following, to get the minimum per month

```
SELECT
      amt
    , valuation_dt
    , min_in_month
    , 'note'
FROM (
      SELECT
            amt
          , valuation_dt
          , net_ValueWOBankAcct
          , MIN(net_ValueWOBankAcct) OVER (PARTITION BY fi_group_cd, year(valuation_dt), month(valuation_dt)) AS min_in_month
          , 'note'
      FROM dba.summary_by_fin_grp
      WHERE fi_group_cd = 'RBCFG'
      AND valuation_dt >= '2017-08-01' AND valuation_dt < '2017-12-01'
      ) d
WHERE net_ValueWOBankAcct = min_in_month
```

Note the change in he "partition" which now includes year and month

Comment: thank you, I'll try that. your suggestion is far easier and simplistic method. I will also try add max for each month, hopefully I will get that right

Comment: oops, seem like we forgot to group or partition by yyyy+mm, we only get one single entry for previous month. effectively it's just the min amount for the the previous 5 months

Comment: Not sure what you mean,  the second query does partition by year and month.  If the where clause extends to more than a single month then you need the second query.

Comment: pardon me for missing the 2nd sql and my weakness in sql,  
   
using the 2nd sql, I'm getting syntax error near 'AS' on line 11  
   
the line for "Over (Partion by...)

Comment: Sorry a closing parenthesis was missing, put a ) just before the AS

Comment: fantastic. Thank you @Used_By_Already . I should have spotted the missing parenthesis. I'm now string to combined that with max_in_Month in the same row but I'm having trouble getting the valuation_dt for the max_in_Month.  looks like I have use union instead of trying to get both max and min in the same row

Comment: *I'm having trouble getting the valuation_dt for the max_in_Month* I don't understand: `valuation_dt` is a column from the query and will appear in the row that represents the max value of the month, that's the whole point of the query really

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161039/discussion-between-gg89-and-used-by-already).

Comment: That suggestion occurred at ~ 02:48 my local time.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is the best way but I got the result in the format I need from the following. the only fault is there is  a possibility of duplicate entry for a given month if either the min_in_month column or max_in_month is not unique
I know used_by_Already said not to use between but between is defined inclusive and work from sql 2008 and many other mainstream db

```
Begin
declare n int;
declare aDt date;
declare dt1 date;
declare dt2 date;
declare nullDt date;
declare nullBal money;

select 7, today(), null,null into n, aDt, nullDt, nullBal;
// no EOFMonth in sql 2008
select dateAdd(month, -n-1, aDt - Day(aDt)+1) into dt1;
select aDt - Day(aDt) into dt2;

SELECT
      Latest_Bal
    , min_Dt
    , min_in_month
    , max_Dt  // Need to get this value somehow?
    , max_in_month
    , YearMth
 into #temp
  FROM (        
      SELECT
            null as Latest_Bal
          , nullDt as max_Dt
          , valuation_dt as min_Dt
          , net_ValueWOBankAcct
          , datepart(Year, valuation_dt)*100+datepart(mm, valuation_dt) as YearMth
          , MIN(net_ValueWOBankAcct) OVER (PARTITION BY YearMth) AS min_in_month
          , MAX(net_ValueWOBankAcct) OVER (PARTITION BY YearMth) AS MAX_in_month

      FROM dba.pf_dailyvaluation_summary_by_fin_grp
      WHERE fi_group_cd = 'RBCFG'
      AND valuation_dt between dt1 and dt2
      ) d

   WHERE net_ValueWOBankAcct = min_in_month --or net_ValueWOBankAcct = max_in_month 
    ;

update #temp t
set t.max_dt=(select first valuation_dt 
 from dba.pf_dailyvaluation_summary_by_fin_grp f
  where t.YearMth = year(f.valuation_dt)*100+month(f.valuation_dt)
     and net_ValueWOBankAcct= t.MAX_in_month )
;

select * from #temp;
drop table #temp;
end
```